# Windows 7 - Can't update my program's files in C:\Program Files

Tags: windows, windows-7, uac

I have an addin program that works with MS Word (version 2007).  It is located in the C:\Program Files location.  I installed Windows 7 and then went to make a routine change to my files in this location and it would only bring up a read only file.  How can I grant myself permission to write to my own program?  I cannot change this location or use any other workaround.  I have this product out to 25 different companies and I can't change the programming to work from any other location.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could also embed a **manifest** in your EXE that makes your program require adminrights on Windows 7 / Vista.

Comment: +1 Actually that's quite a good idea! It might bring home to the OP that allowing users to write to program files isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Vista, UAC means that users run without admin rights and don't have write access to the program files directories.

The correct solution is to write to a folder for which standard users do have write permissions.

The solution you are looking for is to make your app's folder within program files writeable to all users.  You can do this by adding a DACL when installing.  It is extremely bad practice to allow standard users to write inside the program files directory and I urge you instead to re-code your app so that it does not need to write there.

Comment: I am the ony one that writes to this folder.  The users only run the program from this folder, just like any other program.  I am the programmer, so I need rights to modify my own files.

Comment: @Julie That's not how it works. You don't write those files. The user writes those files. Permissions are granted to users and not to programs. I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but you must simply realign your expectations. Don't expect your program to be able to write to the program files directory. Those are the rules nowadays.

Comment: I just tried to take the read only attribute off of the Program Files folder, but I still get read-only when I try to open a file.  I just figured there should be an easy way of taking the read-only attribute off.  thanks for any help

Comment: I'm afraid there are no quick fixes like read-only attributes. Eventually understand what I'm saying!!

Comment: Our comments got crossed, I didn't see your response until now.  Sorry, I'm not explaining myself very well.  I have a simple addin for Word, the global template goes in the startup folder.  The program's files go in the Program Files folder, along with all the other programs.  I am tring to open one of those files to make a change to the actuall program.  I moved the program out to the C drive so I could work on it, but it would be nice to just go into the program folder and make the routine change.  It doesn't get changed when it's being used by the user.  Thanks

Comment: OK, you only want to work on this for development purposes? I'm a bit slow catching on. You could grant yourself write access to that folder on your own machine (Right-click | Properties | Security etc. in Explorer). But surely it's better to be able to develop in a dedicated development folder.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much for your time.  Yes, based on your comments I am going to create a development folder, that is a better choice.

Comment: David, I have a program that is installed to program files\my company, when it detects an update it tries to download those files, but it can't. Sure you want to protect the program directory, but program updates are not data, and do not belong in documents directory.  Keep documents and programs seperate.  How is this handled?

Comment: @gerry You are expected to create a subfolder of %CommonAppData% at program install time. Has to be then since admin rights needed for shared folders like common app data. Give this folder a permissive ACL so that you write to it later when your program runs as standard user. That's your download site for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're doing this as part of modifying the config (and not when your application is running for regular users)...

Your user account probably doesn't have the correct permissions to write/modify the file. Assuming your account is an administrator account, right-click the file, select "Properties". Click the "Security" tab. Click edit and give your user account Full Control.

If you can't do this, it's probably because the ownership of the file doesn't allow you. If this is the case, click on "Advanced", go to the "Owner" tab, and click "Edit".

However, if it needs these permissions when it's running, you should instead be using the %AppData% folder.

Comment: While not the right solution if designing an app, this is a helpful answer if you need to edit a file right here and now.