# How to my app can writable files which without running under administrator

Tags: windows, windows-7

My app is developed on Win 7. I login as a standard user and run my app under administrator(rights-click and select 'Run as Administrator'), the program can write files in 'Program File'. But if I run the app by double-click, the app run fail.

I don't want to set UACs on manifest file because it always shows UACs prompt.

how can I set writable privilege or admin rights for my app?

Please help me,

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only app under administrator can write in 'Program Files'. You should use %AppData% for common tasks.

Comment: Hi Kirill! thanks so much. Can I adjust privilege for current process to write files in 'Program Files'?

Comment: There is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6281696/780488.I can add that when I had this problem I run separate process from my app. This separate procces requests admin rights from users.

Comment: @Anglejoy - If you could, what would be the use for UAC?