# Updating own software in Program Files

Tags: delphi, winapi, installation, updates

I have a single executable which, via InnoSetup, installs into Program Files\FolderName by default. The exe has a 3rd party component which goes online to check for new versions and downloads them, then does a bit of fiddling to replace the exe - simple stuff. The problem is, it can't do this in Program Files because of the necessary security there. I was reading [Windows 7 - Can't update my program's files in C:\Program Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281696/windows-7-cant-update-my-programs-files-in-c-program-files) in which David Hefferman gives a solution but then **seems** to say it's a bad idea - but I don't know whether the bad idea bit refers to his solution or to the OP's comments!

So what is the preferred method by which a program can update itself? One that will work on XPSP3 to Win8. I can't seem to find the right phrase to enter into Google that gives me relevant results. Ignore digital signatures and suchlike for now, for simplicity.

(Please note, it may look like I worded that as an opinion question but it's not - there must be some MS-endorsed way of doing it that I can't find. FWIW this is a Delphi program but any Win32 notes will do)

Comment: Putting a permissive DACL under program files is not the solution to your problem. I answered a question directly, and then gave commentary that stated that the proposed solution was a bad idea. So, no, don't contemplate a DACL under program files. If you want to download an update, download to a writeable location and then if you need to update program files you'll need your updater to elevate.

Comment: Right, to me it was a little ambiguous and not helped by the OP's comments, hence starting a new question than adding to that question - didn't want to mount confusion on top of my own uncertainty! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 3rd party update utility needs to be run with administrative privileges, you can achieve that programmatically.

There is nothing wrong with installing your application in Program Files, that is the designated purpose of this folder. However, user data that is used by the application should be stored in a different location.

However you run that 3rd party Utility, you should first check the Windows OS version to see if fiddling with UAC is really necessary(Vista+...) and then run the utility in the elevated state.

Comment: When I say component, it's actually compiled in with the application it updates (not even a DLL/BPL). So the program that wants to update itself would have to run in an elevated state which is not ideal. However, it's interesting that you say it can be done programmatically - I'll have to look into that. Data is certainly written in the user knownfolders. Thanks.

Comment: I understand but UAC is there and you will have to address it if you want to update, either elevating when the application starts or elevating when the need to update arises.

Comment: Yes, I know why ACL is there and that it needs to be addressed, but wasn't sure the best way of doing so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

He says its "extremely bad practice" to fiddle with your system so that normal users can write in "Program Files".

If your program is in "Program Files" it's installed with System Admin rights. So updates need also be installed with System Admin rights.

You can configure InnoSetup to request admin-rights so you can write to "Program Files" but if the 3rd party component does not do this its best to install everything in an other directory.

i.e. C:\Your_Program

That way your 3rd party component can write there.

Comment: Hmm, so I *think* you're both saying, ordinary users shouldn't be able to update software? That makes sense now. I don't want C:\My_Program, that'll go down like a lead balloon with the users.

Comment: If its just your own program i think the best option is to pack your app.exe in an update.exe with innosetup. If update is newer download and execute update.exe. If windows needs elevation during update it will prompt the user. (With or without a password depending on their setup) You could make an innosetup with a /silent switch and restart you program after execution with a minimum of user intervention. A complete silent update does not seem possible if your program does not run elevated constantly (which it schould'nt)

Comment: Other programs that self-update seem to be able to do so without elevation which I think is what's confusing me. If my software causes an elevation prompt then that's fine - the main thing is to get it to work in the "appropriate" way!

Comment: @GeoffM, that's because the files that this "other apps" are updating are not located in the folders that are protected.

Comment: Even Google Chrome installs itself into C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application. This enables their program to modify itself without administrative privileges.

Comment: Peter, I did wonder that. I haven't got any evidence either way on that one so I'll take your word for it. rvk - good point and an interesting idea (whether a good idea or not I'll leave others to decide!).

Comment: @GeoffM,what Google does is interesting for sure. It is however not what MS intended. Obviously the rationale is that malicious programs cannot get installed in program files without explicit consent.Sadly, this increases the threshold for installing evaluation versions of beautiful software. That being said, I actually wanted to add that if you want to update a resource (eg a new virus table) you could do that. That should go to programdata and the security descriptor of your subfolder in programdata may be altered to allow modification without elevation.

Comment: -1 Installing programs outside of Program Files is bad practice because it breaks windows security model.

Comment: It did seem odd to install outside PF, I have to admit. Just checking I wasn't missing a trick here - seems not.

Answer (score -1):

There are several options here:

- The easiest: make updater as a separate program with manifest, which requires admin privileges. Also you can ask for admin privileges when you start your updater. Or you can move your updater into out-of-process COM object instead of separate exe.
- You can create hidden user with admin rigths during installation of your program. Then you will run your updater with credentials of this user.
- You can install system service during installation of your program and this service will run from system account. So your updater will be implemented as a service.

Comment: Create hidden user with admin rights? Install service under system account? Both really poor practise.

Comment: Some times you need to be able to update your software without prompting for credentials. But if you don't need this, then separate updater with proper manifest will be the best choice.